# SQL Запрос на сравнение данных из двух таблиц и перенос в третью

Tags: mysql, sql

Структура таблиц:

```
pinfo_spell
race | class | spell | active

player
guid | race | class

player_spell 
guid | spell | active
```

Необходимо сравнить таблицы `pinfo_spell` и `player` по `race` и `class`, совпавшие результаты вставить в таблицу `player_spell` по `guid` (из таблицы `player`), `spell` и `active` (из таблицы `pinfo_spell`).
 В результате мы должны получить данные из двух таблиц, объединить и перенести их в третью.

Comment: insert into player_spell select p.guid,ps.spell,ps.active from player p, pinfo_spell ps 
where p.class= ps.class and p.race = ps.race

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После соединения таблиц возможны дубликаты, так что лучше добавить DISTINCT:

```
INSERT INTO player_spell (guid, spell, active)
SELECT DISTINCT p.guid, s.spell, s.active
FROM player p
  JOIN pinfo_spell s ON p.race=s.race AND p.class=s.class
```

и ещё, если вам не нужны дубликаты в payer_spell при повторных вставках, вам следует вставлять только новые значения:

```
INSERT INTO player_spell (guid, spell, active)
SELECT DISTINCT p.guid, s.spell, s.active
FROM player p
  JOIN pinfo_spell s ON p.race=s.race AND p.class=s.class
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM player_spell ps 
  WHERE ps.guid=p.guid AND ps.spell=s.spell AND ps.class=s.class
)
```

Сама задача немного странная. Вы теряете информацию о том, из каких значений race и class получились guid, spell, active.

Answer (score 2):

Подойдет?

```
INSERT INTO player_spell (guid, spell, active)
SELECT p.guid, s.spell, s.active
FROM player p
JOIN pinfo_spell s ON p.race=s.race AND p.class=s.class
```